# Como llamar un script (.php .css) ubicado en una sub carpeta dentro de un sitio web en servidor CentOS 7?

Tags: php, sql-server, servidor, centos

**Quiero poder acceder a los archivos que estran en las sub carpetas dentro de mi sitio web ubicado en centos 7, el tema es que antes me funcionaba bien, pero en mi localhost, hace poco compre un dominio y cree VirtualHost en mi servidor httpd en CentOS 7 y ahora me sale un error, es como si no lograra encontrar la ruta de las sub carpetas que contienen estos archivos(.php, .css, .js)**

```
<?php

require_once "./model/views-model.php";

class viewsController extends viewsModel{

    public function getTemplateController(){
        return require_once "./views/template.php";
    }

    public function getViewsController(){
        if(isset($_GET['view'])){
            $rutes = explode("/", $_GET['view']);
            $request = viewModel::getViewsModel($rutes[0]);
        }else{
            $request = "login"; 
        }

        return $request;
    }
}
```

**Ese es el script que quiero trato de llamar desde mi index.php, este es el codigo que uso en mi index, pero ahora lo necesito usar desde mi servidor web en CentOS 7**

```
<?php
require_once"./core/config-general.php";
require_once"./controller/views-controller.php";


$template = new viewsController();
$template -> getTemplateController();
```

**Estan en mi sitio web visto desde mi navegador me sale este error:**

```
getTemplateController();
```

Comment: Bueno no se si sea problema de rutas, pero lo que si te puedo decir es que la clase viewsController no tiene constructor ¿Seguro que es la misma versión de php?

Comment: _El problema era con las versiones de PHP, gracias parcero._

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser por los espacios entre $template y -> ...

```
$template -> getTemplateController();

$template->getTemplateController();
```

También puedes colocar lo siguiente para mostrar los errores:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once"./core/config-general.php";
require_once"./controller/views-controller.php";


$template = new viewsController();
$template -> getTemplateController();
```

Igual te da un poco más de información.